# Call a function in PLSQL with dynamic variable name

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

is there a way to call a function in Oracle using a dynamic variable name? I am trying to call DBMS_LOB.COPY with dynamic column 1...10.

I can do this :

```
DBMS_LOB.COPY(dynamicColumn1 , l_clob, n_size_clob, 1,  clob_offset )
```

But I can't do

```
execute immediate  'select DBMS_LOB.COPY(dynamicColumn' || '1' ||  ', l_clob, n_size_clob, 1,  clob_offset ) from dual;`
```

Comment: what's the error you're getting? Exclude semicolon (`;`) at the end of your SQL statement

Comment: After removing semicolon as your suggested,it says ORA-00904: "DBMS_LOB"."COPY": invalid identifier

Comment: seems like you lack the privileges to access DBMS_LOB.copy

Comment: @Sathya, if that was the case, it should have thrown the same error when I try to use `DBMS_LOB.COPY(dynamicColumn1 , l_clob, n_size_clob, 1,  clob_offset )`

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why people always try to use `SELECT ... FROM dual`.

DBMS_LOB.COPY is a **procedure**, thus you cannot used it in a SELECT statement. You can use only functions in a SELECT.